# D Flip-Flops at MCU IOs

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, flipflop, isolation

I found below PCB from a machine. It has a MCU for control all inputs and outputs and MCU inputs and outputs go through [HCT374](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54hct374.pdf) IC to optocouplers that isolate all inputs and outputs.

What is the application of this D Flip-Flops?

[image]

Comment: They do what flipflops do, I'd guess. Do you understand what a flipflop does? The way we answer this would depend on that.

Comment: Yes. I know the action of D Flif flop. The input state of flip flop transfer to output while only at rising edge of the clock pulse.

Comment: We can't possibly know but one reason could be that they are all on the same data bus to save IO pins or to connect all the data IO to a common bus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that there's a multi-flipflop IC in the path between MCU output and optocoupler will have multiple reasons:

- **drive strength**: The LED within an optocoupler needs some defined current – the MCU might simply not be able to supply or sink current  for each LED or for the sum of all. The flipflop output might be able to do that!
- **level translation**: The LEDs might want a different voltage than what the MCU can directly supply; a flipflop with a different supply voltage might solve that. Same in the opposite direction.
- **stability**: If the MCU crashes or browns out, these flip flops would ensure the output state gets preserved. Some flipflop ICs (not this, I think) do also have Schmitt-trigger inputs to increase noise/ringing immunity
- **synchronicity**: This very much depens on the MCU, but usually, you can switch only a limited amount of outputs at a given time (for example, one output bank a 8 outputs, at most). If it's critical that switching of a greater number of output happens within a very short time frame, it would make sense to switch the MCU outputs in what ever order and time you want and can, and then latch all flipflop outputs at once using a single latch output.
- **versatility**: as long as you don't touch the latch line, you can do whatever you want to the MCU outputs without changing the state of the optocouplers' inputs. So, if your MCU has run out of pins, and you don't have to switch the optocouplers all the time, then this is an easy way of getting two usable outputs out of one pin. This theory is supported by the fact there's vias in the signal lines going to the flipflops on your photo.

Comment: the last point on versatility is true and I have it in my design to keep the MCU with lower pin count package. Nice answer!

Comment: Thanks. Descriptive ansawer

Comment: I used this technique to add more outputs than the micro supported.  I also used octal buffers to add more inputs.